# How to get all class names in a namespace in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a module `Foo`, that it is the namespace for many classes like `Foo::Bar`, `Foo::Baz` and so on.

Is there an way to return all class names namespaced by `Foo`?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
Foo.constants
```

returns all constants in `Foo`. This includes, but is not limited to, classnames. If you want only class names, you can use

```
Foo.constants.select {|c| Foo.const_get(c).is_a? Class}
```

If you want class and module names, you can use `is_a? Module` instead of `is_a? Class`.

Comment: This is a great answer. You sort of forget sometimes that constants in ruby are anything that _starts_ with a capital, so class names are constant instances of type class. +1

Comment: @jcaudle Ruby does *not* lazy load classes. You're thinking of Rails.

Comment: Make sure you load all the classes before: `Dir["app/models/foo/*.rb"].each {|file| load file}`

Comment: @espinchi When giving Rails-specific advice, it is best to say so. Otherwise it might confuse people.

Comment: This only works for classes that have been previously loaded.

Comment: This is NOT the correct answer, as it depends on the autoloader and loading strategies. When your class is never referenced/ needed, thus the file never looked-up via the autoloader, the class will not be listed with the constants. The reference of constants will NOT contain all the constants, because of this issue.

Answer (score 42):

If, instead of the *names* of the constants, you want the classes themselves, you could do it like this:

```
Foo.constants.map(&Foo.method(:const_get)).grep(Class)
```

Comment: I *love* point-free programming. Is my Haskell showing through?

Comment: I'll buy you a beer for this answer!

Comment: This answer was best but ensuring it was defined prevents crashes from things like Module::MODULES

`Module.constants.select(&Module.method(:const_defined?)).map(&Module.method(:const_get)).grep(Class)`

Answer (score 16):

In short no. However, you can show all classes that have been loaded.
So first you have to load all classfiles in the namespace:

```
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/lib/foo/*.rb"].each {|file| load file}
```

then you can use a method like Jörg W Mittag's to list the classes

> Foo.constants.map(&Foo.method(:const_get)).grep(Class)

Comment: This approach is problematic if you are inspecting modules at runtime

Comment: This is the ONLY correct answers, as it omits the workings of the autoloader!

Answer (score 14):

This will only return the loaded constants under the given namespace because ruby uses a lazy load approach.
So, if you type

```
Foo.constants.select {|c| Foo.const_get(c).is_a? Class}
```

you will get

```
[]
```

but after typing:

```
Foo::Bar
```

you will get

```
[:Bar]
```

Comment: Make sure you load all the classes before: Dir["app/models/foo/*.rb"].each {|file| load file}

Answer (score 1):

This alternative solution will load and show *all* classes under `Foo::` including "nested" classes, e.g. `Foo::Bar::Bar`.

```rb
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/lib/foo/**/*.rb"].each { |file| load file }
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |c| c.to_s.start_with? "Foo::" }
```

Note: `**/*.rb` recursively globs.

If you want to include the `Foo` class itself, you could change your `select` to e.g. `{ |c| c.to_s =~ /^Foo\b/ }`