# How does the "#map(&proc)" idiom work when introspecting module classes?

Tags: ruby, constants, introspection, idioms, proc

#### Presenting the Idiom

I found an [interesting but unexplained alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3680719/1301972) to an accepted answer. The code clearly works in the REPL. For example:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def baz
    end
  end
end
Foo.constants.map(&Foo.method(:const_get)).grep(Class)
=> [Foo::Bar]
```

However, I don't fully understand the idiom in use here. In particular, I don't understand the use of `&Foo`, which seems to be some sort of closure, or how this specific invocation of #grep operates on the result.

#### Parsing the Idiom

So far, I've been able to parse bits and pieces of this, but I'm not really seeing how it all fits together. Here's what I *think* I understand about the sample code.

1. `Foo.constants` returns an array of module constants as symbols.
2. `method(:const_get)` uses [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method) to perform a method lookup and return a closure.
3. `Foo.method(:const_get).call :Bar` is a closure that returns a qualified path to a constant within the class.
4. `&Foo` seems to be [some sort of special lambda](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html#method-i-lambda-3F). The docs say:

   > The & argument preserves the tricks if a Proc object is given by & argument.

   I'm not sure I fully understand what that means in this specific context, either. Why a Proc? What "tricks," and why are they necessary here?
5. `grep(Class)` is operating on the value of the [#map method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map), but its features are not obvious.

   - Why is this #map construct returning a greppable Array instead of an Enumerator?

     ```
     Foo.constants.map(&Foo.method(:const_get)).class
     => Array
     ```
   - How does grepping for a class named Class actually work, and why is that particular construction necessary here?

     ```
     [Foo::Bar].grep Class
     => [Foo::Bar]
     ```

#### The Question, Restated

I'd really like to understand this idiom in its entirety. Can anyone fill in the gaps here, and explain how the pieces all fit together?

Comment: Hah! I thought that code looked familiar. Now I realize why ;-)

Answer (score 9):

`&Foo.method(:const_get)` is the method `const_get` of the `Foo` object. Here's another example:

```
m = 1.method(:+)
#=> #<Method: Fixnum#+>
m.call(1)
#=> 2
(1..3).map(&m)
#=> [2, 3, 4]
```

So in the end this is just a [pointfree](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) way of saying `Foo.constants.map { |c| Foo.const_get(c) }`. `grep` uses `===` to select elements, so it would only get constants that refer to classes, not other values. This can be verified by adding another constant to `Foo`, e.g. `Baz = 1`, which will not get `grep`ped.

If you have further questions please add them as comments and I'll try to clarify them.

Comment: I know this is an old answer to an old question, but I'm still struggling with what `&m` really is. I get that it's supposed to be #to_proc, but I can't introspect it directly, so I'm not really grokking how mapping over it really works since repeated calls to `m.call 1` will always return `2` and *m* holds a singleton method that doesn't take an argument. Can you clarify?

Comment: You don't map "over" `m`, you map `m` over the range `(1..3)`. `m` is an instance of `Method`, which is bound to 1. The `+` method requires two arguments though, so if you check the arity of `m`, you'll see it still takes one more argument (`m.to_proc.arity == 1`). Just manually convert it to a proc, assign it to a variable and play around with it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Your parse of the idiom is pretty spot on, but I'll go through it and try to clear up any questions you mentioned.

### 1. `Foo.constants`

As you mentioned, this returns an array of module constant names as symbols.

### 2. `Array#map`

You obviously know what this does, but I want to include it for completeness. Map takes a block and calls that block with each element as an argument. It returns an `Array` of the results of these block calls.

### 3. `Object#method`

Also as you mentioned, this does a method lookup. This is important because a method without parentheses in Ruby is a method call of that method without any arguments.

### 4. `&`

This operator is for converting things to blocks. We need this because blocks are not first-class objects in Ruby. Because of this second-class status, we have no way to create blocks which stand alone, but we can convert `Procs` into blocks (but only when we are passing them to a function)! The `&` operator is our way of doing this conversion. Whenever we want to pass a `Proc` object as if it were a block, we can prepend it with the `&` operator and pass it as the last argument to our function. But `&` can actually convert more than just `Proc` objects, it can convert anything that has a `to_proc` method!

In our case, we have a `Method` object, which does have a `to_proc` method. The difference between a `Proc` object and a `Method` object lies in their context. A `Method` object is bound to a class instance and has access to the variables which belong to that class. A `Proc` is bound to the context in which it is created; that is, it has access to the scope in which it was created. `Method#to_proc` bundles up the context of the method so that the resulting `Proc` has access to the same variables. You can find more about the `&` operator [here](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2008/06/what-does-do-when-used-as-unary.html).

### 5. `grep(Class)`

The way `Enumerable#grep` works is that it runs `argument === x` for all x in the enumerable. The ordering of the arguments to `===` is very important in this case, since it's calling `Class.===` rather than `Foo::Bar.===`. We can see the difference between these two by running:

```
    irb(main):043:0> Class === Foo::Bar
    => true
    irb(main):044:0> Foo::Bar === Class
    => false
```

`Module#===` (`Class` inherits its `===` method from `Method`) returns `True` when the argument is an instance of `Module` or one of its descendants (like `Class`!), which will filter out constants which are not of type `Module` or `Class`.
You can find the documentation for `Module#===` [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D).

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to know is that:

**`&` calls `to_proc` on the object succeeding it and uses the proc produced as the methods' block.**

Now you have to drill down to how exactly the `to_proc` method is implemented in a specific class.

### 1. Symbol

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    Proc.new do |obj, *args|
      obj.send self, *args
    end
  end
end
```

Or [something like this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc). From the above code you clearly see that the proc produced calls the method (with name == the symbol) on the object and passes the arguments to the method. For a quick example:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(&:+)
#=> 6
```

which does exactly that. It executes like this:

1. Calls `:+.to_proc` and gets a proc object back `=> #<Proc:0x007fea74028238>`
2. It takes the proc and passes it as the block to the `reduce` method, thus instead of calling `[1,2,3].reduce { |el1, el2| el1 + el2 }` it calls
   `[1,2,3].reduce { |el1, el2| el1.send(:+, el2) }`.

### 2. Method

```
 class Method
   def to_proc
     Proc.new do |*args|
       self.call(*args)
     end
   end
 end
```

Which as you can see it has a different implementation of `Symbol#to_proc`. To illustrate this consider again the `reduce` example, but now let as see how it uses a method instead:

```
def add(x, y); x + y end
my_proc = method(:add)
[1,2,3].reduce(&my_proc)
#=> 6
```

In the above example is calling `[1,2,3].reduce { |el1, el2| my_proc(el1, el2) }`.

Now on why the `map` method returns an Array instead of an Enumerator is because [you are passing it a block](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map), try this instead:

```
[1,2,3].map.class
#=> Enumerator
```

Last but not least the `grep` on an Array is selecting the elements that are `===` to its argument. Hope this clarifies your concerns.

Answer (score 2):

Your sequence is equivalent to:

```
c_names = Foo.constants #=> ["Bar"]
cs = c_names.map { |c_name| Foo.__send__(:const_get, c_name) } #=> [Foo::Bar]
cs.select{ |c| Class === c } #=> [Foo::Bar]
```

You can consider `Object#method` as (roughly):

```
class Object
  def method(m)
    lambda{ |*args| self.__send__(m, *args) }
  end
end
```

`grep` is described here http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep

`===` for `Class` (which is subclass of `Module`) is described here http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D

**UPDATE**: And you need to `grep` because there can be other constants:

```
module Foo
  PI = 3.14
  ...
end
```

and you probably don't need them.