# How to get all classes in namespace without manually loading the classes?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module, namespaces

I'm looking for a way to list all classes defined inside a module (namespace).
Here is similar question regarding the problem:
[How to get all class names in a namespace in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676274/how-to-get-all-class-names-in-namespace-in-ruby)

but see the last reply, the `Module.constants` is empty until the class is called/loaded. Is there any way to do this without manually referencing each class?

I'm trying to use this feature in Rails 3.2, and the only way I found was requiring each class in initializer (didn't try it but it still requires manual typing...).

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could glob the files in a namespaced directory as such:

```
Dir.glob('/path/to/namespaced/directory/*').collect{|file_path| File.basename(file_path, '.rb').constantize}
```

So in a Rails initialization file or model you could do:

```
Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, "app", "models", "my_namespace", "*")).collect{|file_path| File.basename(file_path, '.rb').constantize}
```

Comment: it's a bitdirty, but I guess it would do the job, so the ansewer accepted, through i decided to keep track of classes in an array.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Building on what Bryan provided, you can use this to get constants/classes from a specific parent namespace, even with filenames/classnames that start/end with some string:

```
require 'pathname'

# make this the directory you are autoloading from
autoload_dir = File.join(Rails.application.root, 'app', 'models')

# this will return FooBar::BarFoo::**::*Boo constants and autoload them
Dir.glob(File.join(autoload_dir, 'foo_bar', 'bar_foo', '**', '*_boo.rb')).collect{|pathname| Pathname.new(pathname.chomp('.rb')).relative_path_from(Pathname.new(autoload_dir)).to_s.camelize.constantize}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bryan Liff's short and elegant answer is almost right, but throws an error. Instead, try:

`Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, "app", "models", "my_namespace", "*")).collect{|file_path| File.basename(file_path, '.rb').camelize.constantize}`

Note the use of `camelize`. I would have posted this in a comment but don't have sufficient reputation to do so.